# Evaluate alternatively $\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\pm\sin^4x\right)dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

In my recent article [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/349642210_Generating_functions_involving_binomial_coefficients_4nchoose_2n_it%27s_squared_reciprocal_and_their_closed_forms_for_hypergeometric_expressions) at Researchgate on page no 9, I was able to deduce the following two identities from the general result (which I treat it as **Theorem 3.2**). Those two identities are

> $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\sin^4x\right)dx =\frac{7\pi^2}{12}-\frac{25}{4}\ln^2(2)-4\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\right)+2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{2-\sqrt 2}{4}\right)-\operatorname{arcsinh}^2(1)+3\ln(2)\operatorname{arcsinh}(1)\approx 0.581222\cdots$$ also

> $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\sin^4x\right)dx=\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt 2}{2}\right)+4\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt 2}{2}}\right)+\frac{\pi^2}{3}-\frac{19}{4}\ln^2(2)+2\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt 2-\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}}{2\sqrt 2}\right)-\frac{\operatorname{arcsinh}^2(1)}{2}-\ln^2\left(\sqrt {2}+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)-3\ln(2)\ln\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt 2}-\sqrt {2}\right)\approx -0.32379\cdots$$

These two beautiful identities  are the special cases of general result $$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\pm16v\sin^4x\right)=\text{Result of theorem  3.2}$$for all $v\leq 1/16$.
However, my interest is to seek an *alternative path* for both general result  as well as those two special cases mentioned above other than technique used in the article.
If there are other ways I would be glad to known.
Using the same technique  one can easily find the  closed form for the integral of type $$\displaystyle  \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\pm256w\sin^8x\right)dx , \;\; |w|\leq 1/256$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Version of 14.04.21.}}$

The given integrals can be expressed via the generalized hypergeometric function:

\begin{align}
&I_\pm =\dfrac2\pi \int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\operatorname{Li_2}(\pm\sin^4x)
=\dfrac2\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{(\pm1)^k}{k^2} \int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sin^{4k}x\,\text dx
=\dfrac1\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{(\pm1)^k}{k^2}\,\operatorname B\left(\dfrac12,2k+\dfrac12\right),\\[4pt]
&I_+ = \dfrac1\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac1{k^2}\,\operatorname B\left(\dfrac12,2k+\dfrac12\right)
= \dfrac38\operatorname{_5 F_4}\left(1, 1, 1, \dfrac54, \dfrac74;\dfrac32, 2, 2, 2;1\right),\\[4pt]
&I_+ \approx 0.5081222068073732302023528705866145091793935116040652847025683994...
\\[4pt]
&I_-=\dfrac1\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{(-1)^k}{k^2}\,\operatorname B\left(\dfrac12,2k+\dfrac12\right)
= -\dfrac38\operatorname{_5 F_4}\left(1, 1, 1, \dfrac54, \dfrac74;\dfrac32, 2, 2, 2;-1\right),\\[4pt]
&I_- \approx -0.323792143703370467535820065099172050645186814259075110252039257...
\end{align}
(see also [WA integration 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5Einfty%20Beta%281%2F2%2C%202k%2B1%2F2%29%20%2F%20%28pi%20k%5E2%29), [WA approximation 1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%2F8%20HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%205%2F4%2C%207%2F4%7D%2C%20%7B3%2F2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%7D%2C%201%5D&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D), [WA integration 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5Einfty%20%28-1%29%5Ek%20Beta%281%2F2%2C%202k%2B1%2F2%29%20%2F%20%28pi%20k%5E2%29),
[WA approximation 2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3%2F8%20HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7B1%2C%201%2C%201%2C%205%2F4%2C%207%2F4%7D%2C%20%7B3%2F2%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%7D%2C%20-1%5D&assumption=%22ClashPrefs%22%20-%3E%20%7B%22Math%22%7D)).

On the other hand,
\begin{align}
&I_+ =\dfrac4\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{1+(-1)^k}{k^2} \int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sin^{2k}x\,\text dx
= \dfrac2\pi\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{1+(-1)^k}{k^2}\,\operatorname B\left(\dfrac12,k+\dfrac12\right),\\[4pt]
&I_+ = \left(\dfrac{\pi^2}3 - 4\ln^2 2\right) +\left(-2\ln^2(2\sqrt2-2) 
+ 4\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\dfrac{1-\sqrt2}2\right)\right); \\[4pt]
&I_- = \dfrac4\pi \Re\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{i^k}{k^2} \int\limits_0^{\large^\pi/_2}\sin^{2k}x\,\text dx
= \dfrac4\pi\Re\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \,\dfrac{i^k}{k^2}\,\operatorname B\left(\dfrac12,k+\dfrac12\right),\\[4pt]
&I_- =-\ln^2\dfrac{1 + \sqrt2 + \sqrt{2\sqrt2+2}}4
 + 4\operatorname{arccot}^2\left(1 + \sqrt2 + \sqrt{2\sqrt2+2}\right)\\[4pt]
& + 8\Re\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\dfrac{1 - \sqrt{1 - i}}2\right),\\[4pt]
\end{align}
with the same numerical results (see [WA test1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%28pi%5E2%2F6-2log%5E2%282%29-ln%5E2%282%20%28-1%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%20%2B%202%20Li_2%281%2F2%20-%201%2Fsqrt%282%29%29%29), [WA test2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-log%5E2%28%281%20%2B%20sqrt2%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt2%29%29%29%2F4%29%20%20%2B%204%28cot%5E%28-1%29%281%20%2B%20sqrt2%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt2%29%29%29%5E2%29%20%2B%208%20Re%28Li_2%281%2F2%20%281%20-%20sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29%29%29)).

The additionall links are: [Int1Sum1](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5Einfty%202%20Beta%281%2F2%2C%20k%2B1%2F2%29%20%2F%20%28pi%20k%5E2%29), [Int1Sum2](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5Einfty%20%28-1%29%5Ek%202%20Beta%281%2F2%2C%20k%2B1%2F2%29%20%2F%20%28pi%20k%5E2%29), [Int2Sum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_%28k%3D1%29%5Einfty%20%28i%5Ek%20Beta%281%2F2%2C%20k%2B1%2F2%29%204%2F%28pi%20k%5E2%29%29), [Int2ReSum](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%20Im%20%282%20i%20%281%2F2%20log%28Im%28sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29%5E2%20%2B%20%281%20%2B%20Re%28sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29%29%5E2%29%20-%20log%282%29%20-%20i%20cot%5E%28-1%29%28%282%5E%283%2F4%29%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%29%2F2%5E%283%2F4%29%29%29%2Fsqrt%282%20-%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%29%5E2%20-%204%20i%20Li_2%281%2F2%20-%20e%5E%28-%28i%20%CF%80%29%2F8%29%2F2%5E%283%2F4%29%29%29), [Int2Final](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-2%20%282%20%28%281%2F2%20log%281%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%29%20-%20log%282%29%29%5E2%20-%20cot%5E%28-1%29%281%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt%282%29%29%29%29%5E2%29%20-%204%20Re%20%28%20Li_2%281%2F2%20%281%20-%20sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29%29%29%29).

**Edit**

[Also](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim_%28t%20to%201%20%2B%20sqrt2%20%2B%20sqrt%282%20%281%20%2B%20sqrt2%29%29%29%20%28-log%5E2%28t%2F4%29%20%2B%204%28cot%5E%28-1%29%28t%29%29%5E2%20%2B%208%20Re%28Li_2%28e%5E%28i%20atan%20t%20%2B%20i%20pi%29%20%2F%282%20sqrt%20t%29%29%29%29%2C%20with%2064%20digs),
$$I_- =-\ln^2\dfrac t4 + 4\operatorname{arccot}^2 t
 + 8\Re\operatorname{Li_2}\left(\dfrac{e^{\large i\arctan t+i\pi}}{2\sqrt t}\right),$$
where
$$t = 1 + \sqrt2 + \sqrt{2\sqrt2+2}.$$

Additional links: [AbsLiData](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7C1%2F%281%2F2%20%281%20-%20sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29%29%7C), [ArgLiData](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arg%281%2F2%20%281%20-%20sqrt%281%20-%20i%29%29).

Comment: Thank you for putting down you efforts to provide an alternative way for the results.  Your final results still seems mysterious to me (though by WA check they are found to be correct). Regarding the hypergeometric one which i had too mentioned  in the cited paper however, the second one seems much curious to me.

Comment: @Naren Thank you for the comment! Typo fixed, links added.

Comment: @Naren Thank you for the bounty. Is something unclear?

Comment: Hi Yuri! I understood your method. You simply do method of  bisection. However, Comparing your closed form and with mine we are able to  deduce the Real part of $$\Re\hbox{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-\sqrt{1-i}}{2}\right)$$ easily.

Comment: @Naren Hi, I am glad for your achievements! Sadly, all my attempts are not successful.