# the integral PDF $\sqrt {{2 \over \pi }} \int_{t\, = \,0}^\infty {e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\left( {v^{\,2} /t^{\,2} + 2t} \right)} dt\,} $

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals

In  my answer  [to this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4056138) I came to the conclusion that  the PDF of the volume of a parallelepiped with normal distributed coordinates,
having one vertex at the origin, is
$$
p_t (v) = \sqrt {{2 \over \pi }} \int_{t\, = \,0}^\infty
  {e^{\, - \,{1 \over 2}\left( {v^{\,2} /t^{\,2}  + 2t} \right)} dt\,} 
$$
with the corresponding CDF
$$
P_{\,t} (v) = \int_{t = 0}^\infty
  {\,\,t\;e^{\, - \,\,t} \,{\rm erf}\left( {{v \over {\sqrt 2 \,t}}} \right)dt\,} 
$$
where $0 \le v$.

I wonder whether these two integrals may have an interesting expression in terms of known functions.

Comment: There are nice expansions. Are you concerned ?

Comment: yes thanks, they could be of interest to understand the properties of this PDF

Comment: Series added to the answer

Comment: Simplification was successful [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043620/evaluate-alternatively-int-0-frac-pi2-operatornameli-2-left-pm-sin4/4093703#4093703), but the proposed integrals look unchangeable...

Comment: [Sometimes it's just luckier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4123446/how-to-evaluate-sum-k-3-infty-frac-ln-kk2-4/4130154#4130154)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of the Meijer G function

$$p_t (v) =\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi }\,\, G_{0,3}^{3,0}\left(\frac{v^2}{8}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,\frac{1}{2},1
\end{array}
\right)$$

$$P_t (v) =\frac{2}{\pi }\,\, G_{1,4}^{3,1}\left(\frac{v^2}{8}|
\begin{array}{c}
 1 \\
 \frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},0
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

In terms of series, for small values of $v$
$$p_t (v)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}-v+$$ $$\frac{v^2 \left(-2 \sqrt{2} \log (v)-2 \sqrt{2} \gamma
   +\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2} \log (8)+\sqrt{2} \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)}{4 \sqrt{\pi
   }}+$$ $$\frac{v^3}{6}+O\left(v^4\right)$$
$$P_t (v)=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} v-\frac{v^2}{2}+\frac{v^3 (-6 \log (v)-9 \gamma +11+\log
   (8))}{18 \sqrt{2 \pi }}+O\left(v^4\right)$$

For large values of $v$, using $v=t^3$
$$p_t (v)=\frac{4t}{\sqrt{3}}\,e^{-\frac{3 t^2}{2}} \left(1+\frac{5}{18 t^2}-\frac{35}{648 t^4}+\frac{665}{34992
   t^6}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^8}\right)\right)$$

$$P_t (v)=1-\frac{34}{9 \sqrt{3}}e^{-\frac{3 t^2}{2}}\left(\frac{18 t^2}{17}+1-\frac{35}{612 t^2}+\frac{1925}{33048
   t^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{t^6}\right)\right)$$

Comment: I see, thanks  ..no hope then to get it in a simpler form.

Comment: @GCab. The notion of simple or not is relative ! Back to serious, I do not think that I could do simpler. But these are just hypergeometric functions. Cheers ;-)

Comment: well, of course .. what I was expecting is that they were part of a class of distributions .. I haven't heard of "Meijer's distributions" (!?)

Comment: but I am starting to learn about now thanks to [this paper](https://www.research.manchester.ac.uk/portal/files/49057443/Meijer_G_RAMA.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, Claude, the asymptotic for large value is in particular interesting .

Comment: @GCab. What I found interesting is how they look after $v\to t^3$

Comment: In fact, and the substitution is quite natural, since $v$ is a volume.

Comment: @GCab. Amazing ! I made it to provide nicer equations. Don't repeat it : I don' t know anything in this domain (and many other, be sure). Cheers :-)

Comment: @GCab My various attempts fatally leads to Meijer G function, with different parameters set.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov. I also think that we are in a no-end loop around various versions of Meijer G function.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov: well, it would be interesting to know the alternative parametrization.

Comment: @GCab Sadlly, I was failed. Nothing new.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov:  thanks for your interest and effort, however. Once special functions come in, it is difficult to find simpler expressions, unless for very special values of the parameters. Meantime I came to learn that the G function is in fact involved in the product of normal variables.

Comment: Is there a proof that are no simpler expressions than MeijerG? Maybe there is a Besselfunction or inserting an Error function in the integral is possible?